# laravel how to use a blade code inside the { }

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my code

```
 <a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/20/edit') }}" class="{{$verticalMenuTab =='Edit' && $verticalMenu == 'Restaurant' ? 'selectedTab' :''}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        Edit Information
                    </a>
```

Instead of the `20` I want to use : `Auth::user()->restaurant_id`

I tried to do this:

```
 <a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/$Auth::user()->restaurant_id /edit') }}" class="{{$verticalMenuTab =='Edit' && $verticalMenu == 'Restaurant' ? 'selectedTab' :''}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        Edit Information
                    </a>
```

but I got the string as it is not the value of it.

could you help me please?

`

Comment: If it is a defined route with a parameter, you could write `URL::route('routename', $Auth::user()->restaurant_id)`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli yes that is a possibility too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 <a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/' . Auth::user()->restaurant_id . '/edit') }}" class= "{{$verticalMenuTab =='Edit' && $verticalMenu == 'Restaurant' ? 'selectedTab' :''}}">
```

Comment: that works, many thanks +1 I will accept your answer when the system allows